# ¿Cuál es la opción uname que imprime la versión del kernel?

Tags: linux, unix, putty

necesito llenar un formulario de la escuela de holberton y me pide que use uname para conseguir el nombre de la versión de kernel he usado `uname -v` y `uname -r` y me arroja la versión de kernel que se usa, pero al momento de responder la pregunta en holberton me sale como erróneo ¿que otro comando puedo usar? o si alguien que ya se haya inscrito en holberton que me pueda ayudar

Comment: `uname -r` es la manera de hacerlo

Comment: Como comenta @fedorqui uname -r debe mostrarte la versión del kernel; otro método sería hacer un cat al fichero /proc/version, y filtrar, quizás mediante grep o awk